# Flutter: Do not scroll to top after insert new items before first

Tags: flutter, listview, bloc

I am working on a MacOs App for browsing pictures using Flutter. One of the main challenges is scrolling over the directories.

I want to display a subset of my pictures. A header and all pictures per directory in a ListView. If the user scrolls down new directories are loaded, appended and comes into view. Thats no problem.

But scrolling up was not easy. If the user scrolls up just after loading I looked for a PointerScrollEvent which worked out up to new. But after I inserted new items at the beginning, the ListView scrolls up to the very first item.

QUESTION: Is it possible, that the scroll flow is still smooth and the inserted items appears one by one as it would, if I scroll down? I hope you get my point.

Here is some code. Just ask, if you need more. I will try to build a sample then.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<DirectoryBloc, DirectoryState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        switch (state.status) {
          case DirectoryStatus.failure:
            return const Center(child: Text('failed to fetch directories'));
          case DirectoryStatus.success:
            if (state.directories.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(child: Text('no directories.'));
            }
            return Listener(
              onPointerSignal: (event) {
                if (event is PointerScrollEvent) {
                  if (event.scrollDelta.dy < 0 && _scrollController.offset == 0) {
                    // emits new state with new directories in the beginning
                    context.read<DirectoryBloc>().add(DirectoryInserted());
                  }
                }
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (index >= state.directories.length) {
                    return const BottomLoader();
                  } else {
                    return DirectoryListItem(directory: state.directories[index]);
                  }
                },
                itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.directories.length : state.directories.length + 1,
                controller: _scrollController,
              ),
            );
          case DirectoryStatus.initial:
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think google employees can't manage that

[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434108/flutter-listview-how-to-add-several-items-on-top-of-the-listview-and-make-it-n)

Also saw 2 similar issues that were closed

Looks like this glitch is by design

Though i tried the solution
[Flutter, ListView, How to add several items on top of the ListView and make it not scroll to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434108/flutter-listview-how-to-add-several-items-on-top-of-the-listview-and-make-it-n)

With two Sliver it really works well!
I saw the explanation that ListView uses Sliver inside